# PHP login system issue - mysql_num_rows is not valid

Tags: php, authentication, mysql-num-rows

UPDATE: changed some sql queries and now it transfers to the control panel. Although it shows these error.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php:10) in /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php on line 74
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php:10) in
>   /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php on line 74
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php:10) in
>   /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/login_success.php on line 76

~Hey guys,

Just using a login script from phpeasysteps.com and it provides the following error when I try to login, Any suggestions

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/checklogin.php on line 27 Wrong Username or Password

Below is the code for the checklogin.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="lewism_lewis"; // Mysql username 
$password="teamgreen"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="lewism_car"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Customers"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Thanks guys,

Ais

Comment: Obligatory "escape your input". Use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- add this
```

Since $result is not a valid handle for mysql_num_rows, find out why the query failed.

Beyond that, I suggest you NOT grab code samples for PHP. most of them, including the stuff you've posted are hideously out of date or outright wrong. At least this one uses mysql_real_escape_string, but it's still using stripslashes and session_register.

Both are deprecated, and the magic_quotes stuff that stripslashes "undoes" is actually outright removed now in the latest PHP version.

Comment: OK I've fixed this by changing the sql select statement to the correct variables.

Comment: Unfortunately it now displays this                                                               Warning: session_register() [function.session-register]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/checklogin.php:2) in /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/checklogin.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/checklogin.php:2) in /home/lewism/public_html/admin/rent/checklogin.php on line 34

Comment: look for that error message on this site. it's been asked/answered about a gazillion times.

Answer (score 0):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)